# Access control on react native

Tags: react-native

I started working on access control in react native, as I am new to react native can anyone suggest me how can I design access control for client side in react native.

Comment: check out https://levelup.gitconnected.com/access-control-in-a-react-ui-71f1df60f354

Comment: Can u explain a little, what are u trying to achieve

Comment: I want to show modules as well as data based on user roles, once the user is logged in based on his role I want to show the things @skmak

Answer (score 0):

1 - Create auth reducer which contains flag {isLoggedIn:false}
2 - when user submits the form with valid credentials, set isLoggedIn to true by dispatching an action eg loginAction()
3 - now u can check if user is logged in or not by checking isLoggedIn in your store (i,e redux store)